# ReactJS app doesn't find svg images when built and run in a Docker container

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, docker

I've built an ASP.NET Core solution that is mainly just a shell for a React app.  It's a card game that uses svg image files to represent the cards.  When I run locally, the cards display as they should.

The issue is that when I build a Docker image and serve it up from Docker Desktop the images no longer show--just a placeholder where each would go.

The each card is the result of a small function:

```
export const Card = (params) => {
    return <img src={'./cards/' + params.card + '.svg'}
        onDoubleClick={() => { params.action( params.card ) }}
    />
}
```

My best guess is that the needed relative path in the docker image needs to be altered somehow so the files can be found.

In the VS solution, the folder structure looks like the following:

```
root
   ClientApp
      public
         Cards    <== card image svgs are here
      src         <==js code here
```

Any suggestions as to what might be causing the Docker version to not display the images?

Perhaps my better questions might be if the structure is something I should be managing in Dockerfile(?) or what a good way to see the structure Docker is using to arrange the files in the container?

**Edit**
I've noticed it doesn't seem to recognize a sub-folder (or I'm not referencing it correctly).  Any images I place is the `public` folder (parent of `cards`) show.

Answer (score 0):

To reference svg in public use:

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/yourPathHere.svg'} />
```

Comment: Thanks.  It doesn't seem to do anything.  Logging its value returns nothing and it still can't find the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, deploying react with nginx into a docker

I used svg in my react app as an imported entity, so I imported the image and placed it as an variable in img.src attribute.

```
import Plus from 'svg/plus.svg'
.
.
.

<img src={Plus} />
```